# What is std::strtoul for unicode

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to convert this code to unicode

```
int fromHex(const supportlib::string_t &s)
{
    return std::strtoul(s.c_str(), NULL, 16);
}
```

`supportlib::string_t` is typedefed to `std::string` or `std::wstring` depending on whether I want to compile with unicode or ASCII.

With most other types I could find a wide version but not for `std::strtoul` so what should I use instead? `std::wstrtoul` doesn't do the trick as with most other types.

I'm using MingW with gcc 4.8.1.

When I compile it in unicode mode, I get this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long unsigned int strtoul(const char*, char**, int)'
```

Comment: How about `std::stoul`? You get an added bonus of it choosing the right version based on whether you pass a wide string or not, so no need to do it yourself.

Comment: I tried that as well, but I get the error that stoul is not in std.

Comment: @chris, So how can I use this?

Comment: @chris, I'm compiling with gcc as C++11 and I always get the error 'error: 'stoul' is not a member of 'std''

Comment: There's a patch for MinGW on one of SO's answers somewhere. Here: http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C99 at least, it's in wchar.h and prototyped like this:

```
unsigned long int wcstoul ( const wchar_t * restrict nptr, wchar_t ** restrict endptr, int base);
```